# Custom 3 dots menu not opening when clicking on it Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, menu, popupmenu

So my pop up menu not wants to show when i click on it. I don't get any errors, I think I need to add some more lines of code. I just don't know what? Below you can see the code of my adapter

```
    public View findViewById(int position) {
    View view = findViewById(R.id.textViewOptions);
    


View textViewOptions = null;
    textViewOptions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        ViewHolder holder;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        //creating a popup menu
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, holder.textViewOptions);
        //inflating menu from xml resource
        popup.inflate(R.menu.chatmenu);
        //adding click listener
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.BlockUser:
                        //handle menu1 click
                        return true;
                    case R.id.MuteNotificationsCH:
                        //handle menu2 click
                        return true;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        popup.show();

    }
});
    return view;
}
```

And this is my xml ("The place where i click and not seeing the pop up menu")

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewOptions"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:text="&#8942;"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I implemented a popup menu. This may assist you in locating the problem in your code.

```
holder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(UserDetailsActivity.this, holder.imageButton);
                    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
                    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                case R.id.popupCall:
                                    //call user
                                    return true;

                                case R.id.popupMail:
                                    //mail user
                                    return true;

                                default:
                                    return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    popupMenu.show();
                }
            });
```